# How to pass namespace in Kubernetes create deployment command

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to define the namespace name when executing the `kubectl create deployment` command?

This is what I tried:

`kubectl create deployment test --image=banu/image1 namespace=test`

and this doesn't work.

And I want to expose this deployment using a `ClusterIP` service within the cluster itself `for that given namespace` How can I do that using `kubectl` command line?

Answer (score 5):

You can specify either `-n` or `--namespace` options.

`kubectl create deployment test --image=nginx --namespace default --dry-run -o yaml` and see result deployment yaml.

Using `kubectl run`

```sh
kubectl run test --namespace test --image nginx  --port 9090 --dry-run -o yaml
```

Comment: Thank you, how can I define the `containerPort` to `8080` in this deployment? is it like `--containerPort=8080` at the end of the above command?

Comment: You can't define ports using `create deployment`. Use `kubectl run` instead.

Comment: what is `--dry-run` here?

Comment: you can get meaning of option keys by adding `--help` to your `kubectl`

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to create a namespace like this

```sh
kubectl create ns test
```

ns stands for namespace, so with kubectl you say you want to create namespace with name test

2. Then while you creating the deployment you add the namespace you want

```sh
kubectl create deployment test --image=banu/image1 -n test
```

Where flag -n stands for namespace, that way you say to Kubernetes that all resources related to that deployment will be under the test namespace

3. In order to see all the resources under a specific namespace

```sh
kubectl get all -n test
```

```sh
--namespace and -n is the same things
```

Comment: Thank you, how can I define the `containerPort` to `8080` in this deployment? is it like `--containerPort=8080` at the end of the above command?

Comment: I think it's better to leave the -n(or --namespace) flag for the end

Comment: If I where you, I would do it inside the yaml file

Comment: So that means, we `should` edit the `yaml` file with `containerPort` manually and we can't set it using the one line of command?

Answer (score 0):

Use -n test instead of namespace=test

Sample with nginx image:

```
$ kubectl create deployment nginx --image=nginx -n test
deployment.apps/nginx created
$ kubectl get deploy -n test
NAME    READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
nginx   1/1     1            1           8s
```

In second case you need to create service and define labels from deployment.
You can find correct labels by runnig something like:
`kubectl -n test describe deploy test |grep Labels:`
and apply service like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test-svc
  namespace: test
spec:

  ports:
  - name: test
    port: 80 # Change this port
    protocol: TCP
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    # Here you need to define output from previous step
```

Comment: Thank you, how can I define the `containerPort` to `8080` in this deployment? is it like `--containerPort=8080` at the end of the above command?

Comment: ```kubectl -n test edit deploy test``` and also change port in service that I've posted before to 8080. Also please use correct labels for selector

Comment: How can I do this with `kubectl` commands without really writing a `yaml`?

Comment: You can use kubectl edit command as I metioned in previous comment

Comment: even with `edit` it is a manual work. I need to do this just with a single command of line and an enter.